# My mobile navigation doesnt appear on Iphones but works with other devices

Tags: css, css-selectors

Im basically building a mobile menu for my website and it doesnt appear only Iphones. I checked with Safari and Chrome in Iphone, both not working. Works with other mobile phones. I use bootstrap

My html is below:

```
 <!-- MOBİL MENÜ ALT BAR BAŞLANGIÇ -->
        <header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="bottom-nav">
      <div class="bottom-nav-item active" style="width:0;">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
        <span id="hamburger" style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
          <span id="kapatici" style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/hesabim.png">
          <a>Hesabım</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/kurallar.png">
          <a>Kurallar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/oranlar.png">
          <a>Oranlar</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/destek.png">
          <a>Destek</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
        </header>
```

I added my html code aswell I dont know why its not appearing on Iphone but
My css is below:

```
.header .bottom-nav {
display:none;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.header .bottom-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  z-index: 99;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px #212121;

}}
```

Comment: Include your HTML please.

Comment: I've added my html aswell

Comment: Any ideas Wais Kamal?